# Display head search result and its sub result

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a web application with php and mysql. Where I am trying to display searched result as following:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
: Model1      Diescription      Price                    :
:       => Model1-Version1     Discription   Price   :
:       => Model1-Version2     Discription   Price   :
:       => Model1-Version3     Discription   Price   :
..........................................................
: Model2      Diescription      Price                    :
:       => Model2-Version1     Discription   Price   :
:       => Model2-Version2     Discription   Price   :
:       => Model2-Version3     Discription   Price   : 
..........................................................
```

I am beginner in this field , so I don't know what it called.

Suppose I have Table (t):

```
------+------+-------+---------+-------+-------------+
carID : make : model : version : price : discription :
------+------+-------+---------+-------+-------------+
1     : BMW  : XX1   : v1      :2345235: Best Car    :
------+------+-------+---------+-------+-------------+
2     : BMW  : XX1   : v2      :33235  : Good Car    :
------+------+-------+---------+-------+-------------+
3     : Audi  : p1   : vp1      :2345  : Best Car    :
------+------+-------+---------+-------+-------------+
```

Search Query:

- `SELECT carID FROM t WHERE price>=2000;`
- Let us consider all cars has been selected.
  Please suggest me a method by which I would accomplish it.

In my research I found this website, using same search display. It may help
[here](http://www.gaadi.com//new_car_research.php?minprice=4000000&maxprice=4500000)

Thank Your for help

Comment: Please clarify your second bullet point. What are you trying to accomplish with the query conditional?

Comment: @AngrySpartan Suppose with any query all carID has been selected from the table, Now what I want to display all selected cars in above mentioned pattern by using PHP. Please visit this link to make it clear[link](http://www.gaadi.com//new_car_research.php?minprice=4000000&maxprice=4500000)

Comment: See Gabriel's answer below. I think that's exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: No, its not what i am looking for. I want to display searched result in a hierarchical form. Suppose 5 cars are selected of same model, then it should first display model name followed all its versions

Comment: Like this?  `$sql = "SELECT carID FROM t WHERE price >= 2000 ORDER BY model, make, version"`. You can add *ASC* or *DESC* after each field name to determine its sort also.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand so much your question... Do you want only show data?

See this...

```
$query  = 'SELECT carID FROM t WHERE price>=2000';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

echo ('<table width="200" border="1">
       <tr>
         <td>carID</td>
         <td>make</td>
         <td>model</td>
         <td>version</td>
         <td>price</td>
         <td>discription</td>
       </tr>');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

echo('<tr>
        <td>' . $row['carID'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $row['make'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $row['model'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $row['version'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $row['price'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $row['discription'] . '</td>
      </tr>');
}

echo('</table>');
```

Comment: @GabrieBiga Please visit this link [HERE](http://www.gaadi.com//new_car_research.php?minprice=4000000&maxprice=4500000) I want something like this. I know these basic concepts. Thanks for your replay

Comment: Do you try something? Post to we see... This page can be construed with this basic concepts.